# Action Bar Sherlock - Tab Icon and Text

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="One"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/subItem1"
                android:title="sub 1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/subItem2"
                android:title="sub 2" />
    </menu>
 </item>
```

I want an icon and title for one of my menu tabs but only the icon shows up, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `withText` :

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

However, it's only a hint and there's no guarantee that your tab will display the text. It depends on the device screen size.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in portrait mode the text will always be hidden.

You might try removing the title of the actionbar and see if this helps.

Try landscape, there you should see icon and text.

Comment: How do I remove the title of the action bar?

Comment: You could set an empty one. Default is the application name, so overwrite it. Have you tried landscape? Do you see the text there?

Comment: I've made the app name blank and tried it in landscape, still no luck.

Comment: Could you provide a small screenshot and could you change "ifRoom" to "always" just for testing?

Comment: How would I upload the screenshot? I've tried always, no luck.

Comment: A simple image hoster like imageshack.us or zimagez.com will do the trick :)